# Is it possible to feed a database table from a XML file?

Tags: sql-server, xml

We have some (stable) data that is saved in some generic database (database that contains a database structure and its data). To be used, this data must be re-written. Currently, we have an application that export this data to XML files to some very specific location.

We need to add this data to some databases. I know it's possible to load XML inside tables, but we'd like a direct link between the XML files and the database tables (reducing data duplication and risk of seeing people update the generated tables instead of using proper methods).

Is that possible?
Would it be very slow?

Comment: This question seems a bit unclear (or perhaps broad) as is.  What do you mean by must be re-written?  How many XML files are there? How large are they?  Is there a good reason to store your data in XML format (as opposed to in relational tables)?

Comment: Why go through XML if you can connect to the source database? What does "generic database" even mean? You can use SQL Server's Import wizard or SSIS to import data from any database as long as there is an ODBC or OLEDB driver for it. You can also load data from many other sources

Comment: Without an (reduced) example of your XML it's hardly possible to give you an advise... Two things for sure: 1) Yes, you can read data from XML as derived table and 2) you can use this data directly or write this into some kind of table structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSIS to import XML files into database tables.  This will work well if the xml files conform to a schema.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3141/importing-xml-documents-using-sql-server-integration-services/